# Ubuntu Jammy (kernel 6.4.8) Virtual box 7.0-10 issue

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, 22.04

New to this forum -
I am having a problem after installing the newest kernel on my Kubuntu Jammy LTS system. 6.4.8

Went through some standard specified corrections. apt purge virtualbox-X
autoremove
install virtualbox-7*
Reboot

Virtual box installs fine!
Guest os's will not run.
Kernel driver issue?
something in the log about gcc-13 missing. Checked it, it's there 'installed'

virtualbox-dkms never finishes installing either. but I don't think it's required.
up until 6.4.0 I had the VM's running just fine without.

anyway, error mentions disable secure boot? - which I don't have on my machine - bios is set to legacy boot.

Also loading a guest OS which is Debian bookworm gives me an error about the kernel driver not installed.
The log files tell me the kernel's don't match. That the one that was used to build the virtual box drv. it different

attempting a modprobe vboxdrv gives me an error saying that /lib/module-6.4.8 *** (blah, blah)
is not there. Sorry I don't have the exact directory listed.
Everything worked post kernel 6.4.0
Not one kernel after has worked to run Virtual box since on my particular system.

I know the newest kernels provide hardware support drivers and more importantly security patches/updates.
I'm not particularly new to Linux, other than the benefit of security patches.
I don't need the newest kernels for hardware updates.
Any advice is appreciated.